# Flex: spark DataGrid displays value other than the current value in dataProvider

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I have 2 flex datagrids on a screen. The user can select one or more rows from either datagrid and move them to the other datagrid. The lower table is empty when entering the application. For example:

```
Item    Color   Price
--------------------
item57  red    $5.55
item62  blue   $5.29
item808 green  $2.21

Row  Item    Color   Price
---------------------------
```

Note there is a column that numbers the rows on the bottom datagrid (only).

When I enter the application and move, for example, 3 rows from the top to bottom grid, the row numbers are fine (they show rows 1, 2, and 3). For example:

```
Item    Color   Price
--------------------

Row  Item    Color   Price
---------------------------
1    item57  red    $5.55
2    item62  blue   $5.29
3    item808 green  $2.21
```

If I then move, for example, row 1 in the bottom grid back to the top...

```
Item    Color   Price
--------------------
item57  red    $5.55

Row  Item    Color   Price
---------------------------
1    item62  blue   $5.29
2    item808 green  $2.21
```

and then back again to the bottom grid...

```
Item    Color   Price
--------------------


Row  Item    Color   Price
---------------------------
1    item62  blue   $5.29
2    item808 green  $2.21
1    item57  red    $5.55
```

the row number is supposed to display 3 because it inserts into the bottom grid at the end of the list, but when it does this, it displays the (old) row number value of 1.

When I debug and look at the dataprovider = _myData, I see the `rowNumber` value for the row in question (for item57 above) equals 3 (as it should). However, it is displayed in the lower datagrid as 1.

**How can the dataprovider value be different than what is displayed in the DataGrid?**

[I can also debug and look at `gridLower` column information, and it also shows the correct value of 3 for `rowNumber` for the data in question.]

The lower datagrid is similar to the following (although I'm using a custom itemRenderer, removed for simplicity here):

```
[Bindable]
private var _myData:ListCollectionView=new ListCollectionView(new ArrayList());
...
<s:DataGrid dataProvider="{_myData}">
    <s:columns>
        <fx:Array>
            <s:GridColumn id="gridLower" headerText="myHeader" dataField="rowNumber"/>  
            ...
```

The function that adds the upper table's row(s) to the lower table is:

```
private function addRow():void {    
    var selectedIndices:Object=gridUpper.grid.selectedIndices;
    for (var i:int=selectedIndices.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        var item:Object=_upperTableData.removeItemAt(selectedIndices[i]);
        item.rowNumber=_myData.length+1;
        _myData.list.addItem(item);
    } 
    // I tried adding "_myData.refresh();" here and it had no effect
    // I tried adding "ListCollectionView(gridLower.dataProvider).refresh();" and it had no effect
    // I tried adding "grid2.dataProvider.refresh();" here but it had no effect
}
```

UPDATE 1: If I re-sort any column in the lower table, the correct values appear. I seem to be observing what's reported in this link:
http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/2007/06/23/another-flex-weirdnessgotcha/
Haven't found a solution yet though. See attempts in my `addRow()` function above. Am I on the right track?

UPDATE 2: While re-sorting manually corrects the data in the lower grid, I haven't found a way to do this programmatically. I tried inserting:

```
_myData.sort=null;
var complete:Boolean=_myData.refresh();
```

just before the end of `addRow()` function above, but it didn't resolve my issue. When debugging, `complete` is true, but still the lower grid displays the stale data.

Comment: can you put some demo somewhere.. i seriously couldn't figure out what you are trying to say

Comment: Thanks Kamal, I added more info to the above description to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer :) I will delete the old one if this helps.

I haven't used Spark DataGrid yet, was expecting it to behave like a List.

Found this in this in some comments in the source for this method of DataGrid:

```
public function invalidateCell(rowIndex:int, columnIndex:int):void
```

You can invalidate an entire row/col by passing -1 for the other value. In the quote from the docs below, you can also use dataProvider.itemUpdated()

> If the specified cell is visible, it is redisplayed. If
>   variableRowHeight=true, then doing so may cause the height of the
>   corresponding row to change. If columnIndex is -1, then the entire row
>   is invalidated. Similarly if rowIndex is -1, then the entire column is
>   invalidated.
>
> This method should be called when there is a change to any aspect of
>   the data provider item at rowIndex that might have some impact on the
>   way the specified cell is displayed. Calling this method is similar to
>   calling the dataProvider.itemUpdated() method, which advises the Grid
>   that all rows displaying the specified item should be redisplayed.
>   Using this method can be relatively efficient, since it narrows the
>   scope of the change to a single cell.

Now I finally know where the itemUpdated() method on collections (ArrayCollection, ListCollectionView) can actually be used!

[edit]

Give your grid an id:

```
<s:DataGrid id="lowerDataGrid" dataProvider="{_myData}">
```

Then you should be able to do this in your `addRow()` method after updating the collection:

```
lowerDataGrid.invalidateCell(item.rowNmber -1, 1); // assuming rowNumbers are 0 based
```

Comment: Looks promising, but I'm not able to figure out how to code it. It seems the compiler doesn't recognize actionscript function `invalideCell()`. Does it need an import? Or, is this mxml (if so, where does it insert in code)? Not sure on the syntax to use to try itemUpdated().

Comment: If it's not recognizing the method `invalidateCell`, you might have imported mx:DataGrid instead of s:DataGrid.

Comment: The rowNumbers begin at 1. Still working on importing something to recognize invalidateCell. It should be `import spark.components;` http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Grid.html#invalidateCell()

Comment: It looks like your `addRow()` method is in the same MXML class as the DataGrid, so you shouldn't need an import. You should be able to use the id of the grid in `addRow()` as shown above. The grid rows are probably 0 index based so maybe a minus 1 :)

Comment: Oh, yah the index of the grid rows starts at 0 (I see why you use -1 now). But whatever I try, I'm just not able to get the compiler to recognize invalidateCell. I'm using (not shown) a custom column class that `extends GridColumn`, maybe that's why(?).

Comment: datagrid have this issue sometime when it doesn't refresh, just a workaround but it generally works, manually set the scroll position of datagrid after moving data back, it ll force the rendered column to be redrawn...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in my main class that contains the grid as an element, whenever I want to force a refresh of all the cells:

```
    gridsDataProvider.addItemAt(new Object(), 0);
    gridsDataProvider.removeItemAt(0);
```

But my GridItemRenderer needs to cater for the change in the data. So I created an updateDisplay method:

```
        private function updateDisplay() : void {
            if (transWindow != null) {
                if (data == transWindow.total) {
                    if (field != "vat" && field != "total") {
                        textInput.visible = false;
                    } else {
                        line.visible = true;
                        textInput.enabled = false;
                        textInput.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
                        textInput.setStyle("fontSize", 14);
                    }
                } else {
                    line.visible = false;
                    textInput.visible = true;
                    textInput.enabled = true;
                    textInput.setStyle("fontWeight", "normal");
                    textInput.setStyle("fontSize", 12);
                }
            }
        }
```

This method is called from both the creationComplete handler ...

```
        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getTransWindow(event.target.automationOwner);
            updateDisplay();
        }
```

... well as the data setter of the GridItemRenderer

```
        override public function set data(v:Object):void {
            super.data = v;
            if (v == null) {
                textInput.text = "";
                return;
            }
            var value : * = v[field];
            if (value == null || value == undefined) {
                textInput.text = "";
                return;
            }
            if (value is Number)
                textInput.text = Number(value).toFixed(2);
            else
                textInput.text = ""+value;
            updateDisplay();
        }
```

The mxml body of my renderer is quite simple:

```
<s:Line id="line" width="100%" visible="false" yFrom="1" yTo="1">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="0" weight="0"/>
    </s:stroke>
</s:Line>
<s:TextInput id="textInput" y="2" restrict="0123456789." width="100%" height="100%" minWidth="10" borderVisible="false" textAlign="right"/>
```

O, in case you wondered, the getTransWindow method is just a method to retrieve the main calling class that contains the grid:

```
private function getTransWindow(par : *) : void {
            if (transWindow != null)
                return;
            transWindow = par;
            while (!(transWindow is TransactionWindow)) {
                transWindow = transWindow.parent;
            }
        }
```

Hope this saves someone some time

Regards
Christo